# Keller's correction to the quantization condition: Calculation of Maslov index

Tags: quantization, semiclassical

I've skimmed over Keller's paper (1958) but I'm still not sure how to calculate the Maslov index for a given Hamiltonian. The quantization condition is given by

$$ \int p\,dq = h(n + \frac{m}{4}) $$

where $m$ is the Maslov index, $(i/2\pi)\Delta(\log A)=m/4$, $A$ is the normalization constant. As it says $m$ is integer for closed orbits, and it is half-integer for open orbits. I appreciate if you can explain to me how to calculate $m$ let's say for $H=xp$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use MathJax for the equations. You might want to check I haven't made any typos.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm new here, I 'll learn to use the MathJax asap.